# Concatenate unsigned char * inside a loop

Tags: c, openssl

I'm using the library OpenSSL for encrypting through AES. Since AES is a block cipher, I need to split the data in chunks of 16 bytes. Thus, if I want to recover the message, I need to unite the chunks at the end of the program.

This is my code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/aes.h>

char key[] = "secretkey123";

int main() {
    unsigned char text_slice[128];
    unsigned char enc_slice[128];
    unsigned char dec_slice[128];
    
    unsigned char in[160];
    
    unsigned char enc_out[160] = "";
    unsigned char dec_out[160] = "";
    
    int i;
    int k = 10;
    for (i = 0; i < 16 * k; i++) {
        in[i] = 'A' + (rand() % 26);
    }
    in[160] = '\0';
    printf("IN:%s\n", in);
    
    AES_KEY enc_key, dec_key;
    
    AES_set_encrypt_key(key, 128, &enc_key);
    
    AES_set_decrypt_key(key, 128, &dec_key);
    
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        text_slice[0] = '\0';
        enc_slice[0] = "\0";
        dec_slice[0] = "\0";
        memcpy(&text_slice[0], &in[15 * i], 15);
        text_slice[16] = "\0";
        printf("TEXT SLICE: %s \n", text_slice);
        AES_encrypt(text_slice, enc_slice, &enc_key);
        memcpy(&enc_out[16 * i], &enc_slice[0], 16);
    }
    printf("ENC:%s\n", enc_out);
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        text_slice[0] = '\0';
        enc_slice[0] = "\0";
        dec_slice[0] = "\0";
        memcpy(enc_slice, &enc_out[16 * i], 16);
        enc_slice[16] = "\0";
    
        AES_decrypt(enc_slice, dec_slice, &dec_key);
        printf("Dec slice:%s \n", dec_slice);
        memcpy(&dec_out[16 * i], &dec_slice[0], 16);
    }
    printf("DEC OUT:%s\n", dec_out);
    
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the program is the following:

```
IN:NWLRBBMQBHCDARZOWKKYHIDDQSCDXRJMOWFRXSJYBLDBEFSARCBYNECDYGGXXPKLORELLNMPAPQFWKHOPKMCOQHNWNKUEWHSQMGBBUQCLJJIVSWMDKQTBXIXMVTRRBLJPTNSNFWZQFJMAFADRRWSOFSBCNUVQHFF
TEXT SLICE: NWLRBBMQBHCDARZ 
TEXT SLICE: OWKKYHIDDQSCDXR 
TEXT SLICE: JMOWFRXSJYBLDBE 
TEXT SLICE: FSARCBYNECDYGGX 
TEXT SLICE: XPKLORELLNMPAPQ 
TEXT SLICE: FWKHOPKMCOQHNWN 
TEXT SLICE: KUEWHSQMGBBUQCL 
TEXT SLICE: JJIVSWMDKQTBXIX 
TEXT SLICE: MVTRRBLJPTNSNFW 
TEXT SLICE: ZQFJMAFADRRWSOF 
ENC:j�Q���
�7֡���*n���R  ��m7�zI#4��=v�#�(��V7��ח9.R�q����:C�%��_��!q��(��l��j�3�1�h��
Dec slice:NWLRBBMQBHCDARZ 
Dec slice:OWKKYHIDDQSCDXR 
Dec slice:JMOWFRXSJYBLDBE 
Dec slice:FSARCBYNECDYGGX 
Dec slice:XPKLORELLNMPAPQ 
Dec slice:FWKHOPKMCOQHNWN 
Dec slice:KUEWHSQMGBBUQCL 
Dec slice:JJIVSWMDKQTBXIX 
Dec slice:MVTRRBLJPTNSNFW 
Dec slice:ZQFJMAFADRRWSOF 
DEC OUT:NWLRBBMQBHCDARZ
```

While `dec_slice` works as expected, `dec_out` just get a copy of the memory of the first chunk. What is more surprising for me, is that `enc_out` performs correctly when following the same logic as `dec_out`. What am I missing?

Comment: You copy 16 bytes into `dec_slice` which (I think) includes the `\0` char.

Comment: @Per Mertesacker This statement in[160] = '\0'; already invokes undefined behavior.:) There is an access to memory beyond the array.

Comment: Unless subsequently encoded in a printable form, an AES-encoding of *anything* is going to be raw octets, each of which can include anything in the range 0x00 through 0xFF. Dumping that to a console isn't going to lead to anything remotely intelligible.

Comment: It looks like this is working as planned. Your program **is** concatenating all of the dec slices together. But the 16th byte in every dec slice is a null terminator (by luck, since you did it wrong when you tried to do it yourself).

Comment: Notice how you concatenate 15-byte chunks when encrypting and 16-byte chunks when decrypting? Why is that?

Comment: Please don't use AES in [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_(ECB)) (eg. encrypt block by block without any form of chaining)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key must have at least 16 bytes since you pass a number of bits equal to 128 in:

```
AES_set_encrypt_key(key, 128, &enc_key);
AES_set_decrypt_key(key, 128, &dec_key);
```

You have undefined behavior here:

```
    in[160] = '\0';
```

These lines don't make sense:

```
    enc_slice[0] = "\0";
    dec_slice[0] = "\0";
    text_slice[16] = "\0";
    enc_slice[16] = "\0";
```

Why do you encode chunks of 15 characters instead of 16?

```
    memcpy(&text_slice[0], &in[15 * i], 15);
```

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/aes.h>

char key[] = "secretkey1234567";

int main() {
    unsigned char text_slice[128];
    unsigned char enc_slice[128];
    unsigned char dec_slice[128];
    unsigned char in[160];
    unsigned char enc_out[160];
    unsigned char dec_out[160];
    
    int i, k = 10;
    for (i = 0; i < 16 * k; i++) {
        in[i] = 'A' + (rand() % 26);
    }
    printf("IN: \"%.160s\"\n", (char *)in);
    
    AES_KEY enc_key, dec_key;
    AES_set_encrypt_key(key, 128, &enc_key);
    AES_set_decrypt_key(key, 128, &dec_key);
    
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        memcpy(text_slice, &in[16 * i], 16);
        printf("TEXT SLICE: %.16s\n", (char *)text_slice);
        AES_encrypt(text_slice, enc_slice, &enc_key);
        memcpy(&enc_out[16 * i], enc_slice, 16);
    }
    printf("ENC:");
    for (i = 0; i < 16 * k; i++) {
       printf(" %02X\n", enc_out[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        memcpy(enc_slice, &enc_out[16 * i], 16);
        AES_decrypt(enc_slice, dec_slice, &dec_key);
        printf("Dec slice: %.16s \n", (char *)dec_slice);
        memcpy(&dec_out[16 * i], dec_slice, 16);
    }
    printf("DEC OUT: \"%.160s\"\n", (char *)dec_out);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems in that code.

The `AES_set_encrypt_key` and `AES_set_decrypt_key` are not key derivation functions, the second parameter is supposed to represent the length in bits of the first parameter (`userKey`).

If you provide an arbitrary string constant like `"secretkey123"` with a length that is not 128 in bits, it may cause memory corruption or create a very insecure context for your encryption.

In general, for user password based encryption, we generate a key from any password using a key derivation function (for example `PBKDF2`, or `scrypt`).

This line is also bad:

```c
in[160] = '\0';
```

Since the buffer has a size of `160`, the last index should be `160 - 1`. If you write at index `160`, you are actually overflowing.

Also, you must really notice the difference between single quote and double quotes when writing C code.

This is bad:

```c
enc_slice[0] = "\0";
dec_slice[0] = "\0";
```

If you use double quotes, you are not actually writing the value `0` at the first index of `enc_slice` and `dec_slice`. You are writing the address of an empty read-only constant string.

Also this:

```c
unsigned char enc_out[160] = "";
unsigned char dec_out[160] = "";
```

If you want to have empty buffers, you should just do:

```c
unsigned char enc_out[160] = {0};
unsigned char dec_out[160] = {0};
```

Hopefully this is a good start to improve your code and make it work.